# In Lisp, how do you add a given element to every list inside a given list?

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, common-lisp

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defun append-all(x L)
  (if (null L)
    L   
    (cons (append (car L) x) (append-all x (cdr L))))
  )
)
```

Output:

```
(append-all '3 '((1) (2 1) (2)))

((1 . 3) (2 1 . 3) (2 . 3))
```

Want:

```
((1 3) (2 1 3) (2 3))
```

This is a helper function, so the fact that it is a linked list seems to be causing me problems.

Thanks

edit: fixed recursive call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, change this part:

```
(append (car L) x)
```

To this:

```
(append (car L) (list x))
```

It wasn't working before because `append` should receive two *lists* as parameters, not a list and an element.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun append-all (item list)
  "Appends ITEM to each sublist of LIST"
  (flet ((circular-list (item)
           (let ((list2 (list item)))
             (nconc list2 list2))))
    (mapcar #'append
            list
            (circular-list (list item)))))
```

Comment: Interesting trick. However `flet` now is not needed (you can just move `mapcar` inside the `let` and use `list2` directly), if instead it's there for readability then it would be IMO even better moving `(list item)` out of it so that the call becomes `(circular-list (list item))`

Comment: @6502: I think using sub-functions in Lisp to increase readability is underrated. If it is of general utility, then it makes sense to move it to the top-level. Having a function already makes that easier...

Comment: I agree... but I'd use `(flet ((circular-list (x) (let ((list2 (list x)) ...)`. A circular list with element `x` is more useful than a circular list where element is `(list x)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd rather not do the recursion yourself, this should also work:

```
(defun append-all (x L)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (l) (append l (list x))) L))
```

Comment: Note that with standard reader case, all symbols are upcased, so `l` and `L` denote the same symbol name.  In the shown code, it works as expected, since `L` is shadowed.

Answer (score 0):

I am learning clisp, but it can work.

```
(defun append-all (x L)
    (flet (
        (append-item (alist) (append alist (list x))))
        (mapcar #'append-item L)))

(print (append-all '3 '((1) (2 1) (2))))
```